# Is there a python library to create draw.io-like schematics?

Tags: python, drawing, latex

I need to create schematics similar to the ones that can be created with draw.io or other similar software like dia, or MS Visio. However, I need to do that with a scripting language, preferably python.

Is there any python library to do that? It would be great if it also has support for latex formulas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dia has some [support for Python scripting](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Python). Theoretically, you could use it to create the diagrams you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [diagrams](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/) library for writing. For the latex notation, you could use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html).

If you need something more abstract or generic, [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) might be what you need. A simpler approach might be to use the [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) [python library](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

N2G is a python library that can be used to create draw.io or yEd diagrams https://github.com/dmulyalin/N2G

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).